# Ubuntu start Node.js server and open Chrome in kiosk mode

Tags: ubuntu, google-chrome, shell-script, cron

I'd like for a computer to immediately start a Node.js application on boot. I'd then like Chrome to open in Kiosk mode, but only after the server has been started. Looking on the Ubuntu Stack Overflow, I found a way to execute a script on startup

> Adding a line to your cron like this:
>
> @reboot /path/to/script
>
> will execute that script once your computer boots up.

I thought I could do this with a .sh script, but I'm new to Linux. If I were to write something like this:

```
node server.js
chromium-browser --kiosk http://example.com
```

Would the chromium-browser command not execute until the node server was completely started?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried that?  If so, what was the result?

I would expect that if you had tried that, it failed.  That's because the process `node server.js` never ends to move on.  Typically in this case, you would use `node server.js &` to send the process to the background; however, that does not mean that the server is ready.

To actually know that, your best bet is to use the `listen callback` to execute the system command.  For example:

```
var http = require("http");

var srv = http.createServer(...);
srv.listen(8000, ExecuteChromium);

function ExecuteChromium() {
    exec("chromium-browser --kiosk http://example.com", function(error, stdout, stderr) {
        console.log("stdout: " + stdout);
        console.log("stderr: " + stderr);
        if (error !== null) {
            console.log("exec errror: " + error);
        }
    });
}
```

Note: This isn't tested as it stands, just looked at some docs an an [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19103735/run-shell-script-with-node-js-childprocess) to execute a command.